# extrude faces from vanishing point

Tags: extrude

i want to extrude the individual faces from the  Cursor point, which i use as a vanishing point - not along the normals. How can i do that?[image]

Answer (score 7):

With the 3D cursor as your Transform Pivot Point:

- <kbd>E</kbd> Extrude
- Right-click to cancel the move (leaving the extrusion in place)
- <kbd>S</kbd> Scale (uniformly, away from the cursor)

[image]

**Edit:**

As @lemon points out in the commentary, <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> will do the trick on its own, without the drop! Which is a lot more Blenderish :)

The only way I can think of, to extrude the faces individually from the vanishing point, is numerically:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Extrude Individual, and drop.
- <kbd>S</kbd> Scale by a numerical amount from the cursor
- Change the Pivot to 'Individual Origins' and Transform Orientation to 'Normal'
- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> scale the faces numerically again, by [1/the previous scale], back to their original size.

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Once again, the comments have come up with a way *not* to go Clunk,Clunk,Clunk.

This time, thanks, @Gordon Brinkmann! The individual-origin scale of a plane is automatically in the XY of its normal, since it has no thickness, and to enter a reciprocal numerically, a leading slash will do. So, move 2, if your outward scale was, say, `3.4`,  is:

- Set Pivot to 'Individual Origins',  and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>

Comment: you can E S directly, without right clicking.

Comment: One could extrude individual faces and then hook each of them to some objects and then use scale in affect only locations mode in object mode to avoid scaling them.

Comment: it is going in the right direction. But I want to extrude the faces individually. If you select "extrude individual faces" it is oriented to the normals. But I want it to be oriented from the cursor. The faces that are extruded should not increase in size, as is the case with "scale".

Comment: or is it possible to move the selected faces along the vanishing point of the cursor? Then I could first extrude the faces individually and then move them. But how?

Comment: @Urban See edit for a possible route..  someone may come up with a simpler one..

Comment: @RobinBetts You don't have to set the _Transform Orientation_ to _Normal_ and use Shift+Z for scaling. When you scale single flat faces with _Individual Origins_ as pivot points, they are automatically scaled on their normal X and Y (because the Z dimension is 0). And as a tip for those who do not know how to scale by the reciprocal value: to scale by 1/3 for example, you do not have to scale with S then enter 0.3333, just enter S, /, 3. The slash after S automatically starts taking the following values as divisor for 1.

Comment: great! thank you Robin so much!

Comment: Thanks, @GordonBrinkmann !   I seem to have accumulated some crud, in the form of muscle-memory 'learned phrases' which I just use, even when they're not the best.